# Mutliple emails on submit

Tags: workflow, infopath

I have created a workflow associated with InfoPath form. When user fills the form and  clicks on Submit . Workflow will kick off and sends an email to user and other groups in email chain, but when ever user is clicking submit twice it is sending two emails. How should I restrict user once submitted the application not to click on submit and not to send second email?
I am using InfoPath 2010 and Workflow is form designer.

Comment: did u used the Action rule "Close the form" for ur infopath Submit button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may add a field either in InfoPath or on the SharePoint List. If you are going to add the field in InfoPath, make sure you just use it in the rules like a hidden field concept.

In your rules, update this field to 'YES' on click of the submit button. Then in your workflow, check for this flag field and add a conditional check to trigger your workflow. This should help resolve your issue.

Also, primarily the double-click on the submit button could be more of a browser issue and i have noticed this as well, when you usually have validations or so on your InfoPath form. Sadly, it is the behavior we have to deal with.

Comment: Hi Yeshwant now the submitted application  when I go back and edit it and save not submit the application is sending emails

Comment: You have to add a condition in your workflow to handle the flag. Have you modified the workflow?

Comment: I have modified the workflow and its workign now but the problem is some of the forms are already submitted and they don't have the new field value so I updated manually for one of them through list and it sent out email. Can we stop sending email when I am updating values on the old forms?how should i do that?

Comment: Ok, awesome you have modified the workflow. Now for the remaining items that have already been submitted, go ahead and update the flag value to the value you are setting in your workflow. 
For eg: 
if you are setting flag value from NO to YES, once email is sent. You will have to update YES as the value on the previously submitted items, such that your workflow is not triggered. Hope this is clear.

Comment: when I am doing so email is sending out on those items.

Comment: That should not be the case, how many workflows do you have? do you have one on item creation and item modification? based on what you are saying, looks like your 'item modification' workflow needs to be checked for the logic. Check your item modification workflow and add the flag condition there as well.

Comment: I have only one workflow which is set to start on creation of item and change in item..i tried same in test environment it is working fine but when i do same in prod it is doing this. I am kind of stuck

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75284/discussion-between-splearner-and-yeshwanth-j).

Answer (score 2):

If the User is double clicking the Submit button, I'm not 100% positive this will work, but if they are clicking Submit, then reopening the form and clicking Submit again, the following will work:

1. Create a checkbox field called "formSubmitted" (default to no value)
2. Add a rule so that when the User clicks the Submit button, set the formSubmitted field to checked (Probably want this to be the first rule that runs)
3. Add a conditional formatting rule to the Submit button that when the formSubmitted field has a value, disable the control (you can also gray out the button as part of this rule).
4. Publish!

Comment: Do you want me to create field in InfoPath or in the list. If I create a field in InfoPath now does that impact other applications which are already submitted?

Comment: Yes, I was recommending in InfoPath, then submitting the field to SharePoint. By default the value will be ` ` (No value) for previously created items. You can go through and set the value manually to have it impact previous forms, then hide the field from your SP list.

Answer (score 2):

i haven't tried form designer, but in SP designer you can tell the workflow when you want it to be fired, when the item is created, when the item is modified and when the item is submitted.

I might be biased, but i would recommend you to switch to SP Designer workflow

--Edit--
on Sp-Designer open your workflow, and on the properties check "star workflow when item is created" and uncheck when item is modified

if you still need to run some part of the workflow when the item is modified, i would move that functionality to a different workflow that start only when the item is modified.

Comment: Hi Erin it is already a SP Designer workflow. Thanks